# What would be the cost for invoking azure management API

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

As a newbie to azure environment, I have the following queries to ask
1. What would be the cost for invoking azure management API (I didn't get any documentation which defines cost)

[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/{workflowName}/runs/{runName}/actions?api-version=2016-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/%7BworkflowName%7D/runs/%7BrunName%7D/actions?api-version=2016-06-01)

2. What would be the better way of maintaining **PROD** and **DEV** environments for logicapps and app services? My current plan is to differentiate it with the resource group. Is this a preferable way to go with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `What would be the better way of maintaining PROD and DEV environments for logicapps and app services? My current plan is to differentiate it with the resource group. Is this a preferable way to go with?` - This question is quite broad.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks for your quick reply, Yes I understand that. The preferable way can vary based on the organizational standard as well. But I'm wondering will there be any issue that i'll face in the future by going that resource group wise separation. Any suggestion would be appreciatable.

Comment: `But I'm wondering will there be any issue that i'll face in the future by going that resource group wise separation. Any suggestion would be appreciatable.` - Again, it's going to be very speculative.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to your questions

> What would be the cost for invoking azure management API (I didn't get
>   any documentation which defines cost)

There's no cost of invoking Azure Management API. However there is a limit on how many API requests you can make (essentially throttling). You can find more information about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/request-limits-and-throttling.